# Syntax error with Jquery's nth-child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to change a series of HTML unordered lists into a table using jquery.

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="FindByCategory">
    <ul>
         <li>list item</li>
         <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
         <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
         <li>list item</li>
         <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to turn it into something that looks like:

```
<div class="FindByCategory">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>list item</td>
            <td>list item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>list item</td>
             <td>list item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>list item</td>
            <td>list item</td>
        </tr>
</div>
```

The approach I'm using is to create and populate the table first and then hide the unordered lists. The problem I'm running into is the with the nth:child selector. I'm getting an error message "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ul:nth-child" on the console. The page is using jQuery 1.6.4

Here is my code:

```
$('.FindByCategory').prepend('<table />'); 
var numberOfRows = $('.FindByCategory ul').length;
for(var i=0; i <= numberOfRows ; i++ ){
    $('.FindByCategory table').append('<tr>');
    var numberOfColumns = $('.FindByCategory ul:nth-child(i) li').length;
    for(var j = 0; j<= numberOfRows ; j++){
        var liHTMLContents = $('.FindByCategory ul:nth-child(i+1) li:nth-child(j+1)').text();
        $('.FindByCategory table tr:nth-child(i+1)').append('<td>' + liHTMLContents + '</td>');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the value of `i`, not the string `"i"` :

```
var numberOfColumns = $('.FindByCategory ul:nth-child('+i+') li').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
 $('.FindByCategory ul:nth-child('+i+') li').length;
```

Same for other lines too.

```
for(var j = 0; j<= numberOfRows ; j++){
   var liHTMLContents = $('.FindByCategory ul:nth-child('+(i+1)+') li:nth-child('+(j+1)+')').text();
   $('.FindByCategory table tr:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').append('<td>' + liHTMLContents + '</td>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
$('.FindByCategory ul:nth-child(i) li').length;
```

should be

```
$('.FindByCategory ul:nth-child(' + i + ') li').length;
```